# C error: expression must have arithmetic or pointer type while accessing union member within structure

Tags: c

Getting error `error: expression must have arithmetic or pointer type` in following code snippet. Not sure whats going wrong.

```
struct structX
{
  union {
    structA varA; /* structA is a structure */
    structB varB; /* structB is a structure */
  } unionX;

#define xa unionX.varA
#define xb unionX.varB 
}

void foo(structX **sxpp) {
  structX *sxp = *sxpp;
  /* i want to do null check for xb */
  if (sxp-> xb) /* error: expression must have arithmetic or pointer type */
  {
     ...
  }
}
```

I tried to deference the pointer as well, something like this, but no success.

```
if ((**sxpp).xb)
```

Comment: It should be `(struct structX **sxpp)` and so on. You can not just drop `struct` out of type name.

Comment: *"i want to do null check for xb"* What is the type of `structB`? If it's not a pointer (and I hope it's not as pointers should not be hidden behind typedef), then doing null check makes no sense.

Comment: When fixing the problem with missing `struct` all over the place, the code compiles fine. So it appears that the problem is not in the posted code. Post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Btw if you upgrade your compiler to standard C, you don't need to use smelly macros like those. Standard C supports anonymous struct/unions.

Comment: If `structB` is a typedef'ed struct then you cannot simply use it in a condition. You need to use a member of the struct.

Comment: Please always provide complete examples. Your code cannot compile without a `typedef`.

Answer (score 1):

In this statement:

```
if (sxp-> xb) { ... }
```

you are trying to evaluate a struct (`sxp->unionX.varB`) as either true or false. Your compiler is trying to tell you that this won't work. The expression inside an `if()` statement must either be an arithmetic value (e.g., `if (i < 10)`, where `i < 10` evaluates to 0 or 1), or a pointer (e.g., `f = fopen("a.txt", "r"); if (f) { ... }`).

You can't evaluate a struct in this way. Did you perhaps mean to check the value of an element of `varB` inside this union?

Answer (score 0):

The problem in the below statement

```
structX *sxp = *sxpp;
```

It should be `struct structX *sxp = *sxpp;`

Or first `typedef` the structure as

```
typedef struct structX
{
  union {
    /* make sure below structure are typedefed above */
    structA varA; /* structA is a structure */
    structB varB; /* structB is a structure */
  } unionX;
}structX;
```

And then create the variable as

```
structX *sxp = *sxpp;
```

Modify the `foo` function accordingly

```
void foo(structX **sxpp) { ... } /* if typedefed */
```

or

```
void foo(struct structX **sxpp) { ... } /* if not typedefed
```

**Edit** : Since your question doesn't explain about `structA` and `structB`. lets say `structB` looks like

```
typedef struct struct_b {
        int y;
}structB;
```

the code block

```
if (sxp->xb) {
            ...
}
```

should be below one if you want to check whether member of `structB` is `NULL` or not

```
if (sxp->xb.y) { /* let say y is data member of structB */
       ...
}
```

Comment: Did you see the comment in the snippet where the error arises? It is obviously not about missing `struct` keyword.

Comment: I modified @Gerhardh